# What I can expect from Visual web Developer 2010, a free tool?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-web-developer

Just wanted to know that does Visual web Developer 2010 [Free tool] contains MVC framework? I want to learn asp.net MVC, this is the reason why I wanted to know that if Visual web Developer 2010 conatins asp.net MVC I can practice it their or is there anything new I can learn from Visual web Developer 2010 ?

Might be you will see this question is not as useful but the main reason is this that I can't afford to buy VS 2010.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, a MVC2 template is installed right out-of-the-box.

Silverlight and WCF too, if you're interested.

Comment: So does it mean that if I install Visual web Developer 2010, I would get MVC framework installed in it? or do I have to install this framework explicit ?

Comment: You get all the libraries and tools, and the 'framework' part is installed on your PC. Deploying to a server is the same as with the big VS2010